# Firefox pdf form displays a "4" in checkbox (instead of a checkmark); Works fine in IE & Chrome

Tags: firefox, browser, coldfusion, pdf.js

I am creating a pdf document (via ColdFusion), but when I preview the rendered pdf in Firefox, I get the number "4" where my checkmarks are supposed to be (see photo below). *When I preview the exact same pdf in Chrome or IE, I see the checkmark, and it all works perfectly!*

I am pre-populating the pdf form fields (via ColdFusion session variables), and then rendering the pdf using the following markup:

```
<cfpdfform source="82040.pdf" action="populate">
   <cfpdfformparam name="org" value="">
</cfpdfform>
```

### Here is the resulting pdf form in Internet Explorer:

*Note how the checkmark is rendered properly:*
[image: the checkmark renders normally in IE]

### Here is the same form previewed in FireFox:

*Note how the the checkbox has a "4" instead of a checkmark:*
[image: In firefox I get a "4" instead of a checkmark]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This should not be related to your back-end code. What HTML does it produce?

Comment: If I had to guess, which I do, I bet there is a line that says `<input type="checkbox" value="4" checked="4" />`

Comment: The code above is not the HTML that is sent to the browser for rendering... Maybe you should start be reading up on server-size code vs client-side code.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: it's a PDF, not mark-up.

Comment: @AdamCameron I realize that is probably the case. But we don't yet know what HTML it is wrapped in or it is being transformed into HTML. Another important piece of info would be what is rendering the PDF (PDF.js / Adobe Reader / etc.).

Comment: Can you show us the line of code that populates the highlighted field?

Comment: This is the pdf I am using to prefill http://www.flhsmv.gov/dmv/forms/BTR/82040.pdf

Comment: Try changing the value to "on".

Comment: I can't edit your PDF at all, even to check the box in Firefox.

Comment: ...I don't think anyone here is going just through to hoops to run your CodeFusion code. Why not add code that CodeFusion source code outputs?

Comment: [What are the difference between server-side and client-side programming?](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming)

Comment: Basically, CodeFusion code runs on the server, and the output (such as HTML) is sent to the client. Firefox reads the client code, there for the output is the code Firefox is have a problem with.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara it's *just sending a PDF file*. That's all CF will be sending. It won't be a mix of HTML and PDF (that doesn't make any sense, for a start). It's basically as if you browse to a URL with a .pdf extension, pointing straight to a static PDF file. All the web server returns is the PDF file. There is no mark-up involved in this.

Comment: @AdamCameron Evidently, it's also modifying the PDF file, not just sending it. Had the OP included both PDF's, this would have been a simple problem. Also, have you really never seen a website that iframed or embeded a PDF document? There are also technologies that transform PDF's to HTML (that's actually how Firefox renders PDF's).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I think the difference here is I understand the CFML code posted and you - with respect - don't. I'm not *speculating* that the PDF doc is all that's being served, I am reading and understanding the code that's being posted. Vicki's CFML code populates a PDF and sets the response to spool the PDF - *just the PDF*, no mark-up - down to the browser.

Comment: @AdamCameron Which, no offense, means the question doesn't actually have anything to do with CodeFusion. Just browser + PDF. Which is what we were trying to get at, but the OP unfortunately doesn't understand what ColdFusion is.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: ultimately, yes. As Leigh points out, it's a Firefox bug. However it was entirely reasonable for the OP to not know that (hence, you know... asking the question). And it was also entirely reasonable for them to think it was how they were manipulating the PDF - with the CFML code - which could be contributing. In the mean time, most of your input has been based on only superficially understanding what's going on. This is still no different from the first time I suggested it.

Comment: @AdamCameron We were trying to help the OP ask a better question. They didn't provide the necessary information to reproduce the issue, so we were trying to help to do so. This could have been a really good question, if it didn't depend on knowledge of a specific feature in some obscure/dieing technology. Sure, those with knowledge of the CF code he was using might not have needed it, but those aren't necessarily the same people with knowledge of Firefox's PDF.js rendering engine. It's fair to say I didn't know what exactly that CF code was doing, but that's why I was trying to get past it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bug was apparently [addressed already](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/3032), as pointed out via the project's github repo: the bug was supposedly fixed during [this commit](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/5251). So if you are still experiencing problems, it either means:

- **You are using an outdated version of the [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) library,**
- **Or, the problem has been re-introduced into the library.**

So to start things off, **you will want to make sure that you are using the most up-to-date version of the pdf.js library**. If you are still experiencing problems, even with the most up-to-date version, then the problem is still within the embedded pdf document viewer, and there aren't too many things you can do to fix this until the project maintainer's finally fix the problem.

The issue you are experiencing (the reason why you are seeing a "4" where there should be a checkmark, is because the pdf.js library is using a special symbol font to render the checkmarks, but in problematic versions of firefox's embedded pdf-viewer the symbol font isn't rendering the checkmark correctly, so it shows a "4" instead of a checkmark -- because the checkmark symbol they are using in the custom font just so happens to be mapped to the number "4".

Similarly, for the same reasons cited above, if you assign the checkbox to render squares (instead of checks), the letter "N" will appear in the checkbox instead of a square, because the square shape symbol is mapped to the letter "N".

This problem **only exists in the embedded pdf document viewer in Firefox** but will look perfectly normal when viewed in Adobe Acrobat Reader, or other offline pdf readers (and other browser pdf readers, which is why it looks fine in Chrome and IE), so when users download the form, it will appear like you would expect it to.

#### Some workarounds / optimizations you could try:

*Try one of these, or all of these, they are in no particular order (or guaranteed to work)*

- Don't rely on the built-in pdf.js browser extension in firefox, instead, [make your own updated version based on the latest pdf.js source](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js#getting-the-code) or target [another pdf library](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) and use it's browser-agnostic API to render and display your pdfs.
- Create an HTML form for the user to fill and verify all the information, then render the pdf  based on the data supplied by the HTML form, **for download only** (no previewing in the browser). This will force them to open the pdf in their default pdf viewer where the issue is not present, because, again, the problem you describe only happens in Firefox's embedded pdf viewer and not in other pdf viewers like Adobe Acrobat).
- Make sure you have the [ZapfDingBats Font](http://www.azfonts.net/load_font/zafdingn.html) installed on your server. I haven't confirmed this, but that commit that was supposed to have solved this issue seems to have added support for this font, so it is worth a try to make sure this font is accessible on your ColdFusion server, then try previewing the rendered pdf in Firefox.
- Detect that the user is accessing your form via Firefox, and if so, warn the users of the issue, but assure them that downloading the form and viewing in their default pdf viewer will work as expected.
- Convert the page to HTML5 (if you aren't already), then add in an [HTML5 shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) (so HTML5 features can be used on older browsers), and a [CSS normalizer](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css), and test if the problem persists using these optimal settings. It's worth a shot to make sure that the problem is somehow treated differently under the HTML5 standard, since not everyone is having the same issues as you.
- Lastly, make sure that your HTML is being rendered as valid markup via your ColdFusion output by using an [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Other than that, there isn't a whole lot you can do until the mozilla team updates their embedded pdf viewer. But since the problem is only in the firefox viewer, and not in the pdf itself, it it up to you to decide if this is a deal-breaker or not, and search for alternatives.

**Note:** [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) is built into version 19+ of Firefox.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**Update:** You can use **[this pdf](http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/TestSuite/contrib/XEP/Tests/zapf-dingbats.pdf)** (which represents the character mapping of the ZapDingbats symbol font) as a way of testing your browser's interpretation of embedded fonts in the pdf rendered via pdf.js. Note that at the time of this writing, the above pdf does **not display the Zapf Dingbats properly in Firefox** (via pdf.js), but other browsers render them just fine (notice the "4" next to `a20[x2714]` in firefox, and the checkmark next to the same entry (`a20[x2714]`) in Chrome.

[image: ZapfDingbats not rendering in Firefox version 34.0.5 via pdf.js]

Comment: Nice, thorough explanation +1.

Answer (score 8):

It is [a bug with Firefox's PDF Viewer](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=846359). Currently, there is no fix. As [radiovisual's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27907136/104223) points out, the bug in the underlying library (pdf.js) was supposedly fixed.  However, there is still the issue of Mozilla updating the older version baked into Firefox (which is what most folks are using). Currently, that bug is still outstanding.

Probably the best you can do is to return the pdf as an "attachment", rather than "inline", so the browser prompts them to "open/save" the file. If the user opts to "open" the pdf, it should open with their default program instead. (Adobe Reader is the default for most users).

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=fileName.pdf">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" .../>
```

Update:

Comment: Downvoter, please leave a comment. I am curious what you think is wrong with the above answer. It is correct and is currently one of the few *server side* solutions.